# Bash - Detect the current OS version and compare it with arithmetical expressions

Tags: bash, shell

```
OS_VERS=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
  if [[ ${OS_VERS} >= 10.14.6 ]]; then
    echo "Bla bla bla..."
  fi
```

I need my code to do something different depending on the OS version installed. If the OS detected version is bigger or equal to 10.14.6 do something, otherwise, do something else. I am using something like this code but it seems the logic is not working.

EDIT: It works if I use `>` or `<` but it doesn't with `>=` or `<=`

Comment: Well, for starters, `10.14.6` isn't really numeric so you can't compare it using `>=`. You could split it into components and check each one individually.

Comment: GNU `sort` with option `--version-sort` might help.

Comment: You really don't want to do this.  Don't test the platform, test the feature.  If there is a particular feature of the OS that is relevant in version >= 10.14.6, then test for that feature.  You don't care that the OS version is a certain number, you care that a particular feature exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
function ver { printf "%03d%03d%03d" $(echo "$1" | tr '.' ' '); }
[ $(ver 10.14.7) -ge $(ver 10.14.6) ] && echo foo || echo bar
```